# Chai + mocha, succeed in test if resolved, fail if rejected

Tags: unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I have a function that returns a promise. In my test file that is using chai I want the following to happen:

```
const result = sendSurveyDataToAnalytics(userId,eventType,eventTitle)

result.then(() => {
    Logger.info("Succeed in the test if we get here")
}).catch(() => {
    Logger.info("Fail in the test if we get here")
});
```

the code explains it. Succeed in then, fail in catch. What is the proper way to do that with maybe expect, or should (already installed chai-as-promised)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `chai-as-promised`:

```
const result = sendSurveyDataToAnalytics(userId, eventType, eventTitle);

result.then(() => {
    Logger.info("Succeed in the test if we get here");
}).catch(() => {
    Logger.info("Fail in the test if we get here");
});

it('resolves as promised', function() {
    return result.should.be.fulfilled;
});

// or:
it('rejects as promised', function() {
    return result.should.be.rejected;
});
```